# On $\pi_n$ commuting with certain functors

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and injective, then $\pi_n(f(X))=f_*(\pi_n(X))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306330/if-fx-to-y-is-continuous-and-injective-then-pi-nfx-f-pi-nx)

This stackexchange poster asked an interesting but naïve question. The category of pointed topological spaces has $0$-objects and thus $0$-morphisms. What if we instead of considering f(X) = im(f) = ker(coker(f)) we define hocoker as the homotopy colimit of the diagram (how do you draw two arrows on top of eachother? Just imagine that there are two arrows on top of eachother) $$X\xrightarrow{0,f} Y$$ and hoker as the homotopy limit of the same diagram. Then if we define hoim(f) = hoker(hocoker(f)) we can rephrase the original question.

Is it true that $f_*(\pi_n(X))=\pi_n($hoim$(f))$ but now we drop the injectivity condition on $f$ since every $f$ is pointwise equivalent to an injective cofibration $X \rightarrow M_f$

The original poster was incorrect essentially because a pointwise homotopy equivalence between diagrams doesn't necessarily induce a homotopy equivalence of colimits or limits. But this is the case for the holim and hocolim functors. For a concrete example, consider the map $I \xrightarrow {1/2} I$ which is a homotopy equivalence and the quotient map $I \xrightarrow f S^1$. Then defining $g = f \circ 1/2$. Then g and f are obviosuly pointwise homotopy equivalent but im$(f)$ and im$(g)$ are not homotopy equivalent.

This is more of an open ended question, please come with your own suggestions of changes or whatever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The command you might be looking for is \rightrightarrows

Comment: I'm confused by your notation.  What do you mean by $hoker(hocoker(f))$? You have defined $hocoker(f)$ as the homotopy coequaliser of $f$ and the trivial map. Then this is a homotopy type rather than a map, so $hoker$ of this, which should be the homotopy equaliser of some map, doesn't make sense. Do you mean to choose a homotopy colimit $K$ together with a map $k_f:Y\rightarrow K$, extend your diagram to $f,\ast:X\rightrightarrows Y\xrightarrow{k_f}K$, and set $hoim(f)=hocoker(k_f)$?

Comment: @Tyrone I assume that this is what's meant : in homological algebra typically $\ker(f)$ can denote both the object and the inclusion map (actually, both) and so $\mathrm{coker}(\ker(f))$ would make sense for instance. OP : I don't know about the open-ended part, but the specific question you ask probably has a negative answer : take the inclusion $S^1\to S^2$, which is a cofibration so the hocoker is just the quotient, so $S^2\vee S^2$, and look at $\pi_2$ of the homotopy fiber of $S^2\to S^2\vee S^2$ : if I'm not mistaken it's not trivial (contrary to $\pi_2(S^1)$)

Comment: Noel points out you need more info in dim $0$. See this article  arXiv:1610.07421v4  (now published in Indagationes, 2018 ) for how you need even more structural info, and to compute broader algebraic structures,  not just groups,   modelling homotopy types,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homotopy equaliser of

$$X\stackrel{f,\ast}{\rightrightarrows}Y$$

is just the cofibre $C_f$ of $f$. Similarly, the homotopy equaliser of

$$Y\stackrel{k,\ast}{\rightrightarrows}C_f$$

is just the homotopy fibre $F_k$ of $k=k_f$. Clearly it is very unlikely that $\pi_nhoim(f)=\pi_n(hofib(Y\rightarrow C_f)$ is going to be isomorphic to $f_*\pi_nX$. One case in which it does happen is if $f$ is a weak equivalence.

In fact the canonical null-homotopy of the composite $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{k} C_f$ gives you a lift $\overline f:X\rightarrow F_k$

and the Blakers-Massey Excision Theorem tells you that if the map $f$ is $n$-connected and the space $X$ is $m$-connected, then $\overline f$ is $(n+m)$-connected. Thus you see that it is in fact very rare that $\pi_nhomin(f)$ is equal to $f_*\pi_nX$.

Max has supplied one example in the comments of where things fail (since $hofib(S^2\rightarrow S^2\vee S^2)\simeq \Omega S^2\times\Omega(\Omega S^2\ast\Omega S^2)$ you have $\pi_2$ of this fibre is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$). Here is an example of my own:

Take a space $X$ and let $f$ be the unique map $f:X\rightarrow\ast$. Then we have

$$hoim(f)\simeq \Omega\Sigma X$$

and clearly $\pi_n\Omega\Sigma X\cong\pi_{n+1}\Sigma X$ is not necessarily trivial whilst $f_*\pi_nX\subseteq\{0\}$.

Comment: Your example is indeed simpler; I chose mine because it had $f$ be a cofibration but I now realize that it is stupid because any map is a cofibration up to homotopy...

Comment: Ok.. is there any way to functorially assign each f a space Ff such that $f_*\pi_n X = \pi_n(Ff)$ then?

Comment: @NoelLundström, I've though a little about this and I don't have a construction of such a space. To me it is doubtful that such an object would exist, although I neither have arrived at any contradiction to its existence. I think its quite an interesting question, really. You might like to pass the question to the experts at math overflow, and see if anyone there has any insight.

Comment: I have thought about it aswell and I came up with the construction of $Ff = \Pi_i \space K(f_*\pi_i(X),i)$. Where the product is taken over all positive i but it's not really a functor since it assigns each morphism $\eta : f \rightarrow g \space$ a set $F \eta$ and not another morphism... Anyhow, thanks for your well written answer!